# How to define subproblem in Dynamic Programming?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I solved several dynamic programming problems but i don't know how to come up with defining a subproblem. For problem [max sum even length subarray](https://csacademy.com/contest/archive/task/max-even-subarray/solution/),  why they define dp[i] = the maximum sum of an even length subarray starting at i.
Do you have any tips or theorem about that? 
thanks in advance.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). This usually suggests that what you need is time with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any theorem about it. It is simply, a matter of training. You should continue doing examples and it will come.

Comment: This is a comment, not so much an answer.